# Property is nil when handling action of UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, null

I have a viewController called `aroundersViewController`. I have a property on the app delegate called `aroundersVC`.

I send an UILocalNotification with actions (interactive notification of iOS 8) from another class called `monitorLocationViewController`.

When I the user taps on an action and `-application: handleActionWithIdentifier: forLocalNotification: completionHandler:` on the `AppDelegate.m` is being called, `mapVC` is nil (actually, on the list `aroundersVC` is "0 bytes" and everything in it is nil):

[image: List]

and I can;t figure out why? I need to change one of `aroundersVC` property (`Arounders` - `NSMutableArray`) but I can;t because it's nil.

** willFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.aroundersVC=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aroundersPage"];

    //Initializing "monitorLocationVC"(MonitorLocationViewController)
    self.monitorLocationVC=[[monitorLocationViewController alloc] init];
    //Setting "monitorLocationVC"(MonitorLocationViewController)'s locationManager
    self.monitorLocationVC.locationManager=self.locationManager;
    self.aroundersVC.locationManager=self.locationManager;

    [self configureLocationManager];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    return YES;
}
```

*AroundersViewController's viewDidLoad*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
#pragma mark - mapView configurations
    //Disabling tilt on "mapView"(GMSMapView)
    self.mapView.settings.tiltGestures=NO;
    //Setting "mapView"(GMSMapView) minimum zoom to 100 (unlimited zoom in) and maximum to 13
    [self.mapView setMinZoom:13 maxZoom:100];
    //Animating map to user's current location
    //[self animateMapToCurrentLocation];

#pragma mark NSUserDefaults fetch
    //Creating "aroundersSave"(NSUserDefaults) to fetch "aroundersSave" (NSUserDefault key for saving all the arounders)
    NSUserDefaults *aroundersSave=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //If "aroundersSave"(NSUserDefaults)'s key "aroundersSave" is nil
    if ([aroundersSave rm_customObjectForKey:@"aroundersSave"]==nil) {
        //Initializing "Arounders"(NSMutableArray) with "New Arounder"(NSString) object
        self.Arounders=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"New Arounder", nil];
    }else //If "aroundersSave"(NSUserDefaults)'s key "aroundersSave" is not nil
    {
        //Initializing "Arounders"(NSMutableArray) with the array at "aroundersSave"(NSUserDefaults)'s key "aroundersSave"
        self.Arounders=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[aroundersSave rm_customObjectForKey:@"aroundersSave"]];
    }

#pragma mark "AroundersTableView" general configurations
    //Adds extra seperator line on top of the tableview
    self.AroundersTableView.tableHeaderView = ({UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.AroundersTableView.frame.size.width, 1.5 / UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)];
        line.backgroundColor = self.AroundersTableView.separatorColor;
        line;
    });
    self.AroundersTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.AroundersTableView.tableHeaderView=nil;

#pragma mark NSNotificationCenter configurations
    //Creating NSNotificationCenter observer for calling "addArounderToArounders:" method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(addArounderToAroundersArray:) name:@"callAddArounderToArounders" object:nil];
    //Creating NSNotificationCenter observer for calling "deleteCellsFromAroundersTableView:" method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(deleteCellsFromAroundersTableView:) name:@"callDeleteCellsFromAroundersTableView" object:nil];
    //Creating NSNotificationCenter observer for calling "getStoresArrays:" method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(getStoresArrays:) name:@"callGetStoresArrays:" object:nil];
    //Creating NSNotificationCenter postNotification for calling "getAroundersArray:" method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"callGetAroundersArray" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.Arounders forKey:@"aroundersArray"]];
    //Creating NSNotificationCenter observer for calling "callMuteOrUnmute" method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(callMuteOrUnmute:) name:@"callMuteOrUnmute:" object:nil];

#pragma mark get user's location
    //Configuring locationManager
    [self configureLocationManager];
    //For showing user's current location
    [self showCurrentLocation];
    //Starting to update user's location
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
#pragma mark addAllStoresMarkers
    [self addAllStoresMarkersToMapView];

}
```

Anybody have an idea what's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some code? Do you ever initialise aroundersVC ?

Comment: @Tander Yes, I initialize `aroundersVC` on `application: willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` like that:
`self.aroundersVC=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aroundersPage"];`

Comment: @Tander Please tell me what part of code you need me to post. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, show me the code in willFinishLaunchingWithOptions as well as viewDidLoad in aroundersVC

Comment: @Tander There are a lot of things that are not related to this on these methods but here you go, updated the post :). Thank you!